# Why do I get "Attempted import error: 'EffectCards' is not exported from 'swiper'"?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I am using Create React App and have imported the way the documentation says to do, since Create React App doesn't support pure ESM packages yet.

```
import { EffectCards } from "swiper";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react/swiper-react.js";
```

But I get the error: `Attempted import error: 'EffectCards' is not exported from 'swiper'.`

EffectFade works fine, so why not EffectCards? Where else is it being exported from to be imported using Create React App?

Comment: Why are you using a package made for mobile to use on web.  Beyond that this package has 131 open issues, is only maintained by one person and even stuff on their own website is broken, like this link https://swiperjs.com/demos#effect-cards, for react.  Their documentation is also pretty poor.  I wouldn't use that package.

Comment: I'm also not sure why you (and their site) say that CRA doesn't support ESM, it does, not only does it use babel to transpile code but also most browsers support ESM.  I'm quite sure they've just never updated their site for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

The official documents stated that: "By default Swiper React uses core version of Swiper (without any additional components). If you want to use Navigation, Pagination and other components, you have to install them first."

To install them:

```
import SwiperCore, { EffectFade, EffectCards } from "swiper";
SwiperCore.use([EffectFade, EffectCards]);
```

Comment: I still get the same error when doing this. EffectFade works without installing as above, but EffectCards doesn't work with or without installing. I am using Reactjs not Native.

Comment: try importing Swiper instead of SwiperCore

Comment: That won't work as it is already imported as Swiper from `swiper/react/swiper-react.js`. I did try it but it throws the error. It doesn't work just importing `import { EffectCards } from "swiper";` either. It's a mystery!

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example? @Archivec's approach works in this example from the official docs: https://codesandbox.io/s/3pgoz?file=/src/App.jsx

Answer (score 0):

In my case ("swiper": "^8.2.2") changing import statements helped

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react/swiper-react.js';
import 'swiper/swiper.scss'; // core Swiper
import 'swiper/modules/effect-cards/effect-cards.scss';
import { EffectCards } from "swiper";
```